# How to install sugarCRM to Apache server

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want install sugar CAM to my machine.

Can anyone guide me how to do it

Comment: how about going through sugarCRM installation guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read sugar installation guide its very easy to install
Please make sure apache is fully configure with php.

please follow link

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Sugar_Community_Edition_Installation_Guide_6.5.0/